# when I do update-grub I get a warning

Tags: command-line, grub2

This is the output of update-grub :

```
    Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

Should I do something to the grub configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to do anything to your configuration. 
I believe it's this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1258597

A line is added that is not supported, but it shouldn't cause any harm.